# Access device data from Watson Iot platform via Web/Window Application like c#

Tags: watson-iot

How can we access device data sent to Watson Iot platform from any device.
We want to access the data via Web/Window Application and show it on our page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but it sounds like you want to view the event data from a device and display it in your web application.

An application can connect to the Watson IoT Platform and subscribe for events from a device in the same org.  Refer to the [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/applications/app_dev_index.html#app_dev_index) for  developing applications for the Watson IoT Platform.

Subscribing to device events

An application can subscribe to events from one or more devices, for example:

```
Subscribe to topic iot-2/type/device_type/id/device_id/evt/event_id/fmt/format_string
```

Note: To subscribe to more than one type of event or to events from more than a single device, use the MQTT "any" wildcard character (+) for any of the following components:

```
device_type
device_id
event_id
format_string
```

Comment: Hi Valerie, Thanks for the information. I am able to get the device data by subscribing to events as mentioned above and I am using c# Client library provided by you guys on GitHub. However, I have couple of questions
1. After some time, event notifications stops coming.
2. If I want to get last event cache data using API call, I am able to get it but it is not giving complete data as received using event subscription OR as shown on my dashboard. My event callback gets hit 2 times for giving me complete data, but in API all I am getting only half part.

Comment: Hi Valerie, continuing from above comment,

3. If I run 2 applications at same time. The previous application's subscription don't work anymore.
4. Sample application provided is a console application, but If I want to use it in Asp.Net Web API, Will it work same like Console application?

Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: I am not sure why your event notifications would stop - if you can provide you 6 character org for the IoT service, I can check logs for errors.  If you are running 2 applications at the same time, be sure they are not connecting with the same client ID.   Two concurrent connections can't be established with same ID - that will cause one of the connections to drop.  I'll check with dev team about other questions you have.

Comment: Organization Id is jt80lq. By Client Id do you mean different API Key and Token combination. If yes, I also tried different API key/token for both applications at the same time, but still got the issue. Let me know if you mean something else by Client Id.

Comment: For the AppID, you should be using unique ID of an application in your organization. 
Refer to documentation - appId is a user-defined unique string identifier for the client. 
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/reference/security/connect_devices_apps_gw.html#connect_devices_apps_gw

Comment: 1. After some time, event notifications stops coming. ?

Event notification may stop if the connection is lost. Auto reconnect will be available soon in the library(https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-csharp/issues/12)

Comment: 2. If I want to get last event cache data using API call, I am able to get it but it is not giving complete data as received using event subscription OR as shown on my dashboard. My event callback gets hit 2 times for giving me complete data, but in API all I am getting only half part.?


Can you please provide the output of the Rest call and the data sent form the device also what you are expecting.

Comment: 4. Sample application provided is a console application, but If I want to use it in Asp.Net Web API, Will it work same like Console application? 
Yes it should work